# Quadratic Casimir operators of $SO(5)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

For $SO(4)$, there are two independent quadratic Casimir operators. In the defining basis where the Lie algebra elements are antisymmetric matrices $\omega_{ab}$ with two $4-\text{indices}$, these are given by

$$ C_2 = \omega_{ab} \omega_{cd} \delta^{ac} \delta^{bd}, $$
$$ C'_2 = \omega_{ab} \omega_{cd} \varepsilon^{abcd}. $$

I'm looking for similar formulas for $SO(5)$. The first one is clear:

$$ C_2 = \omega_{ab} \omega_{cd} \delta^{ac} \delta^{bd}, $$

but the second expression doesn't generalize in a straightforward way to $\varepsilon$ with $5$ indices.

What's the explicit expression for $C'_2$, the second independent quadratic Casimir of $SO(5)$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez how many quadratic Casimirs does $SO(5)$ have then?

Comment: I believe there is always only 1 quadratic Casimir element for a simple Lie group/algebra (corresponding to the Killing form). $\operatorname{SO}(4)$ is not simple so it can have 2 (it has Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(4) = \mathfrak{so}(3) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(3)$). Now $\operatorname{SO}(5)$ is simple so there is only one quadratic element. It is rank 2 so we can find another Casimir element but I believe that is quartic rather than quadratic (see the table [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism)) but I don't know a form for it off the top of my head.

Comment: @Callum thanks. That makes sense, I don’t know why I thought there must be 2 quadratic Casimirs for when the Cartan subalgebra is 2-dimensional.